# Flask app - can't passing a value to a confirmation modal before deleting a post

Tags: flask, modal-dialog, blogs

I need your help with my flask blog app.
I made a simple dashboard listing all the posts, admin can edit or delete any of them. Edit option is fine. But, for delete option, I am trying to implement a confirmation step using a modal. My code is below.

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Dashboard <small> Welcome {{session.username}} </small></h1>
  <a class="btn btn-success" href="/add_article">Add Article</a>
  <hr>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for article in articles %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.title}}</td>
        <td>{{article.author}}</td>
        <td>{{article.create_date}}</td>
        <td> <a href="edit_article/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right"> Edit </a></td>
        <td>

          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            Delete
          </button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Deleting Post </h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this post?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                  <form action="{{url_for('delete_article', id=article.id)}}" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Issue: Form action is generating same url (/delete_article/1) for all posts. 
Please help.
Regards Hossain

Answer (score 0):

The problem was for the reuse of modal id. As the modal code in the loop, so modals for all the post were having the same id. That's why view function was getting the same URL.

Solution (three changes in the above code):

data-target="#exampleModalCenter" -- > data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{article.id}}"

id="exampleModalCenter" --> id="exampleModalCenter{{article.id}}"

and

id="exampleModalLongTitle" --> id="exampleModalLongTitle{{article.id}}"

Answer (score 0):

**Create an element to select the product to be deleted in layout.html**

```
<div id="dvtextRemoveDiv" style="display: none">
        <p class="pintitle"> Select a product name to be deleted from the dropdown: </p>
        <table border="0" width="1000">
        <tr>
            <td>
        
                <p class="pinfield"><select name="KeyValuesRemove" id="KeyValuesRemove" class="form-control" onchange="passKeyToBeDeleted()">
                    {% for row in KeyValuesRemove %}                        
                        <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
                    {% endfor %} 
                   </select>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
                        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

**Create a modal in the same page**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Post?</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <form action="{{ url_for('delete_post')}}" method="POST">
            <input name="pass_value" type="hidden" value="pass_value" id="hidden_input">
            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript function to pass value from html file to views.py (from frontend to backend)**

```
<script>
    
        function passKeyToBeDeleted(){
            var valuefromID = document.getElementById('KeyValuesRemove').value;
            
            $('#hidden_input').val(valuefromID);
            alert(document.getElementById('hidden_input').value);
            $("#deleteModal").modal("show");
        }
</script>
```